# How to create "Singleton" Bean which will hold static hashmap

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, singleton, spring-3

I need to share static hashmaps which will be init on run-time using Spring 3.1.

I need to create a real singleton bean (not necessarily singleton scope) which will hold all my static hashmaps.

The hashmap will be modifiable also in run-time and it has to be available for all my spring beans.

1. the bean that hold the static map has to be alive as long as the application is running
2. the bean need to be accessed by all spring beans.
3. the hashmaps need to be concurrent and thread safe. The hashmap might have like 100 entries and will be accessed in a very high rate.

How could I achive this?  Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is the problem with a normal singleton scope bean holding ConcurrentHashMaps? Why must the maps be static?

Comment: There is no problem with normal singleton bean except the fact that I I need that bean to be alive as long as my application living.

Comment: By "a real singleton bean" did you mean persistent storage for data (after server shutdown and startup data is remembered) or just create new hashmap after server startup? If it's second case, singleton scope is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Kevin's comment (`ConcurrentHashMap` beans), but just found nice Spring 3.1 addition: [`ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/concurrent/ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean.html). The docs says:

> [FactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) for easy configuration of a [ConcurrentMapCache](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/concurrent/ConcurrentMapCache.html) when used
>   within a Spring container.

I found also [this blog post](http://www.silviowangler.ch/2011/09/26/using-caches-in-grails-2-0/), which proposes use of the bean with `@Cacheable` annotation:

```
<bean id="cacheManager"
        class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                  p:name="default"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Haven't tried it but seems nicely integrated with Spring stuff.

Comment: But why would I need caching here? just need a singleton been which will hold static access data that could be modified..

Answer (score 0):

i am not 100% aware about your need but you can create your own scope by section [3.5.5 Custom scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html), this will ensure pure singleton instance and injectable to all beans.  and may be you can solve thread safe by having proper synchronized method or map

Comment: Cant I create a pure singleton instance inject-able without using custom scopes? isnt it a bit overhead for this?

Comment: why do u think that it could be overhead?

Comment: Because I am sure there is already known scope\way which could make a bean as a singleton and globally accessed. that's pretty common feature to have in frameworks.